# HTML5 is working in KINDLE Fire devices?

Tags: html, kindle-fire

is html5 works in KINDLE Fire devices and how to convert the common html file to html 5?

Answer (score 0):

Kindle Fire devices run Android. A variety of web browsers are available for them.

HTML 5 is just the current standard for HTML. Converting an arbitrary HTML document to one that is specifically written in HTML 5 could involve anything from "do nothing" to "replace a wide variety of obsolete markup with modern HTML and CSS". You need to learn HTML in order to do that.